# In google analytics a URL is getting view which does not exsist

Tags: html, wordpress, google-analytics

Let me explain in detail.
We have a html website homepage which fetches recent blog posts from our WordPress blogs page.

Scenario is:

1. Our website URL is www.xxxxx.com/home.html
2. Blogs landing page URL is www.xxxxx.com/resources
3. For showing the recent blogs on homepage we had customized the UI of blogs by creating a separate page as "my-blogs" in WordPress and included this page's URL in iframe inside homepage html as follows:

```html
  <iframe scrolling="no" id="CollabFrame" 
      src="https://www.xxxx.com/resources/my-blogs/" frameborder="0" 
      style="border: 0px none; width: 100%;" target="_top">
      </iframe>
```

Issue is:
When we see the behavior flow in google analytics it shows 80% of traffic is going to "https://www.xxxx.com/resources/my-blogs/home.html" which does not exists. /home.html is getting appended to the https://www.xxxx.com/resources/my-blogs/ from somewhere which we are not able to figure out. Does analytics count scrolls to iframe section?

Please help in finding how the URL is getting appended after a slash and how to remove this link from analytics which is affecting the ratings. Please ask for editing the question if i have failed to explain my problem.

[See Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUEqm.png)

Comment: Check your view settings if somebody has set the default url fields to "home.html" (because this will append home.html to every path that has a trailing slash).

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into your View settings. I suspect that your `Default page` setting has been set to `home.html`. It sounds like you don't need this. Delete the value, and save your settings. Future pageviews won't show up as `/home.html`. Unfortunately your previous hits cannot be changed.